# How to install CHIRP? Can you help? - (Elementary OS 6 Odin)

Tags: system-installation

I purchased Elementary and I have a problem:

- The system does not allow me to install the CHIRP application (https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Download)

Can you help please?

Thanks**

---

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and confirmed that when you click on the flatpak link and choose "Open with Sideload", it hangs forever. You need to install it using the command line.

- Download the flatpak using "Save as…".
- Open Terminal and do `flatpak install /path/to/flatpak`. For example, if you saved it to your Downloads folder, you would do `flatpak install ~/Downloads/chirp-daily-DATE.flatpak`.
- There will be a few prompts, in Terminal and in pop-up dialogs, to enter your password and install runtimes. This is what you should see:

[image: Screenshot of Chirp flatpak being installed from the command line.]

You can uninstall it with `flatpak uninstall com.danplanet.chirp` and then `flatpak uninstall --unused` to remove the extra stuff. Hope this helps!